# Writing a file in PHP with a cron

Tags: php, cron, plesk

I am trying to write a file to a sub folder of the directory my cron script is in using file_ put_ contents. However, I keep getting a warning "failed to open stream: No such file or directory." 
I have this directory structure:

> httpdocs/scripts/fileDirectory

The cron script lives in the scripts folder. I call it with the cron command:

```
php httpdocs/scripts/cron_writeFile.php
```

In the cron_writeFile file, I first tried:

```
file_put_contents('fileDirectory/', $fileName, $fileContents);
```

which works when I load the page in a browser, but not when the cron executes.

When I require_once a file in a cron, I have to put the 'absolute' path to it:

```
require_once('httpdocs/scripts/requiredFile.php');
```

So, I tried that:

```
file_put_contents('httpdocs/scripts/fileDirectory/', $fileName, $fileContents);
```

No luck. I'm pretty sure it's getting to the right folder because the warning is:

> "Warning: file_ put_ contents(httpdocs/scripts/fileDirectory/4.txt): 
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in 
>   /var/www/vhosts/myDomain.com/httpdocs/scripts/cron_writeFile.php 
>   on line 93"

The both directories have write permissions.

I am using a VPS running (I know it sucks and I need to upgrade, but I don't have the authority)
Parallels Plesk Panel version   9.2.1 
with PHP 5.0.4

The file does not exist and I need a new file each time the script runs.
I am not sure if there is a certain way to define the file path or some other thing I am missing.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What if you use `dirname(__FILE__)` ([see](http://php.net/dirname)) to get an absolute path to your "fileDirectory" directory ?

Something like this in your script, I guess, if your `fileDirectory` is a child of the directory where your file resides :

```
file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '/fileDirectory/' . $fileName, $fileContents);
```

That way, you don't depend on relative path, which can be wrong if your script is not launched from the "right" directory.